# Install Appfabric on linux

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, asp.net, cache, mono

I'm developing an asp.net mvc application with the intention to host on linux using mono. I want to use appfabric for caching but seeing as it is built into windows.

I'm wondering if it can also be installed on linux?

Answer (score 1):

No, its windows only.  Will memcached do it?

Comment: I'm looking at memcached and redis. Based on my findings so far, they both support different scenarios. I'm seeking for something with high reads.

Comment: You may want to ask another question about Linux appfabric equivalents.  If its .net mvc you might also consider skipping the server and go directly to azure.